# how i use vba to do a sum on selected sells

Tags: excel, vba

I tried out Macro and this is the formula they give me

```
enter code here
Range("I4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-2]+RC[-1])"
Range("K4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-4]+RC[-1])"
Range("K5").Select
```

I would like to sum Column G+H and result at column I, as well as sum G + J result at column K

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOu3U.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question seems to not to be very clear. Are you looking to get that value at a single cell? at the complete column? Why are you trying to use a macro if it can be done by formulas?

Comment: Hi, i would i would like to get the values from a single cells. I used macro its becos the whole system is already in VBA code so left with the summation part

Comment: With the code you are attaching, at I4 cell you are getting G4+H4 and at K4 you are getting G4+J4, so why not to place the single formula at the cell?. Even, if you are waiting for the input, leave a condition `=IF(AND(G4<>"",H4<>""),G4+H4,"")`. This is what you are looking for???